# How to preserve the order of keys while parsing JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to preserve the order of keys while parsing json data. In the below image original keys are in order "ProgramName,Curtailment1, 2 and so on" but after parsing its arranged in alphabetical order.

I am trying below workaround to fix it but confused how to fill new array with all data in original key order.

```
    var keys = [];

    for (var key in dataset[0]) {  //dataset is parsed json 
        if (dataset[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            keys.push(key);
        }
    }
```

[image]

**Edit**: I am getting keys in original order(in keys array) after iterating keys as shown in above but the problem is i don't know to fetch all records after mapping keys.

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: ok i'll, when i iterate keys they are coming in original order, as you can see programname is at first place and same is coming while iterating(keys) but when i iterate it for values its showing programname at last as shown in image.

Comment: you can make an array of keys then use that to traverse the properties. Try this: ks = Object.keys(dataset[0]); for (var i = 0; i < ks.length; i++) { keys[].push(ks[i])}

Comment: A JavaScript object is an **unordered** collection of key/value pairs. There is no order you can preserve. If you need an order, create an array with the key names in the order you neet them and map that array.

Comment: or maybe you want:     for (var i = 0; i < ks.length; i++) {console.log(dataset[0][ks[i]])}

Comment: i have created new array which consist of correct order of keys, now the issue is how to map these keys and get all records in new array

Comment: With regards @MoritzRoessler's comment, it maybe just luck, but I have always found Object.keys to return the keys in the order they are defined in the object.

Comment: @Nikkorian That's not correct. See this example. `var o = {b:'b', a:'a', "0": "0"}; o.d = 'd'; o['1'] = '1';`. Object.keys returns. `["0", "1", "b", "a", "d"]`. The enumeration order of keys in ES2015 is. *1.* Integer keys in ascending order. *2.* String keys in insertion order. *3.* Symbol keys in insertion order.

Comment: @SunilBamal With an array of keys in the right order it's as simple as `keyArray.map(key => object[key])`.  `var keyArray = ['foo', 'bar']; var object = {'bar': 'a', 'foo': 'b'}`

Comment: thanks @MoritzRoessler.. its working..

Comment: Thanks from me too @MoritzRoessler. Your comment made me reexamine the situation where I use Object.keys and I can see now that I had, happily, inserted the keys in alphabetical order, so when they came out the same way, I made the wrong assumption abut why. I did say "it maybe just luck" so I must have had some uncertainty:)

Answer (score 3):

An `Object` keys in JavaScript are not ordered unlike `Array`. Hence when you use `Object.keys()` or use `for/in` loop on the objects, keys are not promised to be returned in a fixed order.

To solve this issue, you should convert your Data Structure to an `Array` format.  For example, change `{ "CurtailmentDT1": "High Icon", "CurtailmentDT2": "Medium Icon" }` to `[ "High Icon", "Medium Icon" ]` or use a `order` key to maintain the index such as

```
{
  "CurtailmentDT1": { "index": 1, "value": "High Icon" },
  "CurtailmentDT2": { "index": 2, "value": "Medium Icon" }
}
```

Using the `index` key, you can sort the keys/values in JSON.

> You can also use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) Data Structure which is more like an `Object` but it keeps the keys in order.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Uday, i am getting all keys in correct order and i created a new array with correct keys, now i want to map these keys and fetch all records in new array, i need to find how map works for this.